# How to properly place a pgfplotstablestyleset in a floating environment

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I am trying to make a really basic table with values I read from file using `pgfplotstablestyleset`. However, the placing of this table seems completely off. If I use `\centering` it is glued to the right and it overlaps the text instead of being placed before/after it.

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}


\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\SendSettingsToPgf %SiUnitX sends settings to PGF

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
    sigmax  sigmay  sigmaz
    5.1410904452209305e-6   -3.243020222068572e-15  0.002626858897632589
    5.14109044497113e-6 -3.0442457297958973e-15 0.002626858897631923
    5.141090445470731e-6    -2.8261981713164487e-15 0.002626858897632367
    3.814673579619215e-16   1.2769541625971185e-15  0.009197421272315402
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}
A little bit of text.

\begin{table}[tbch]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotstableread{testdata.csv}{\table} %
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            dec sep align=S,    
            fixed zerofill,    
            precision=4,       
            display columns/0/.style={column name=$\braket{S_x}$},
            display columns/1/.style={column name=$\braket{S_y}$},
            display columns/2/.style={column name=$\braket{S_z}$},
            every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
            every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        ] {\table}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This table shows some data}
    \label{tab:myfirsttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't use tikzpicture environment here. You only need it for `pgfplots`. A pgfplotstable is a valid tabular and should be placed independently without TikZ or axis environment..

Comment: A very good example though. Shows the reason at first glance.

Comment: @percusse removing the `tikzpicture` indeed solves the problem.

Comment: @percusse the precision argument doesn't work for the second column, what could be the reason?

Comment: It is `sci zerofill` that you meant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pgfplotstable` is meant to provide an automation framework for creating tabular material. Hence you don't encapsulate it with a TikZ picture to make it work (It works if you place it in a node or `\pgftext` though since they provide a tabular-compatible box or minipage).

Also the alignment is off for columns since you are using scientific notation however using a `fixed zerofill` directive. Instead `sci zerofill` should be used.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,braket,lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,siunitx,booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\SendSettingsToPgf 


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    dec sep align=S,sci zerofill,precision=4,
    display columns/0/.style={column name=$\braket{S_x}$},
    display columns/1/.style={column name=$\braket{S_y}$},
    display columns/2/.style={column name=$\braket{S_z}$},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
] {
sigmax sigmay sigmaz
5.1410904452209305e-6  -3.243020222068572e-15   0.002626858897632589
5.14109044497113e-6    -3.0442457297958973e-15  0.002626858897631923
5.141090445470731e-6   -2.8261981713164487e-15  0.002626858897632367
3.814673579619215e-16   1.2769541625971185e-15  0.009197421272315402        
}
\caption{This table shows some data}
\label{tab:myfirsttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]